# How do I move a file in Python?

Tags: python, file, file-handling, python-os

How can I do the equivalent of [`mv`](https://ss64.com/bash/mv.html) in Python?

```bash
mv "path/to/current/file.foo" "path/to/new/destination/for/file.foo"
```

Comment: for those of you familiar with [gnu-coreutils' `mv` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/mv-invocation.html), python's `shutil.move` has one edge case where `shutil.move` function differs.  [Go here for full write up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813504). **In a nutshell, Python's `shutil.move` will raise an exception (but gnu-coreutils `mv` will not)** when your destination is a directory and the directory already has a file with the same name as the source (again for more info see the link provided in the previous sentence).

Comment: I feel it is extremely unfair to edit a question to match the accepted answer. The question didnt ask to move a file into a file but a file(s) into a directory

Answer (score 2189, accepted):

[`os.rename()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rename), [`os.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.replace), or [`shutil.move()`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.move)

All employ the same syntax:

```
import os
import shutil

os.rename("path/to/current/file.foo", "path/to/new/destination/for/file.foo")
os.replace("path/to/current/file.foo", "path/to/new/destination/for/file.foo")
shutil.move("path/to/current/file.foo", "path/to/new/destination/for/file.foo")
```

- The filename (`"file.foo"`) must be included in both the source and destination arguments. If it differs between the two, the file will be renamed as well as moved.
- The directory within which the new file is being created must already exist.
- On Windows, a file with that name must not exist or an exception will be raised, but `os.replace()` will silently replace a file even in that occurrence.
- `shutil.move` simply calls `os.rename` in most cases. However, if the destination is on a different disk than the source, it will instead copy and then delete the source file.

Comment: Am I the only one that thinks os.rename is not working for directories?  I quote: "If dst is a directory, OSError will be raised."

Comment: `shutil.move` works for directories. You can use relative path `shutil.move(f.name, "tmp/")` or full path  `shutil.move(f.name, "/Users/hello/tmp/")`, **do not use** **`~`** in the path, checked in python2.7.9, Mac OS X.

Comment: `~` is a shell construct, and has nothing to do with file paths per se, other than as a misplaced convention. If you really want to involve your home directory, use `os.getenv('HOME')` instead, concatenating it with parts of your desired path, if necessary.

Comment: You could always use `os.path.expanduser()` to properly expand the '`~`' according to os-specific rules. Much neater since `%HOME%` isn't always set on Windows.

Comment: If you want to use `os` then `os.rename` behaves differently on different platforms if the file exists, instead use `os.replace`

Comment: `os.rename` won't handle files across different devices.

Use `shutil.move` if you are not sure the source and the destination file are on the same device.

Comment: On my Mac, `os.rename` would err with `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`, even though it seemed to work fine (except for throwing the error).  `os.replace` is undefined (python 2.7).  `shutil.move` seems to work fine

Comment: @Fabian It works with directories, but the destination can not be an *existing* directory. If destination is an existing file, it will be replaced. Normally destination should not exist, and if it is a directory, it will not replace that whole directory with something else. `rename` is a simple command with clear semantics. It does not make the assumption to place a file inside a directory if destination is a directory. But you can move whole directories with it.

Comment: I'd like to point out that at least for Windows  running `Python 3.7.3` that `shutil.move` respects the file attributes, both created and modified which is really great. This was a folder to folder move on the same disk. It would be really great to run those experiments for each of the commands above and tabulate the attribute preserving behavior across OS platforms and even drives by the looks of it.

Comment: I do not think this is valid for shutil.move: `Note that you must include the file name (file.foo) in both the source and destination arguments.`

Comment: @ig0774 When you wrote "Note also that in the first two cases the directory in which the new file is being created must already exist" I read that as implying that this is not true for the third case. That's wrong, as I found out the hard way. The destination directories must already exist for `shutil.move()`.

Answer (score 341):

Although `os.rename()` and `shutil.move()` will both rename files, the command that is closest to the Unix mv command is `shutil.move()`.  The difference is that `os.rename()` doesn't work if the source and destination are on different disks, while `shutil.move()` is files disk agnostic.

Comment: `shutil.move()` uses `os.rename()` if the destination is on the current filesystem. Otherwise, `shutil.move()` copies the source to destination using `shutil.copy2()` and then removes the source.

Comment: Take care to realize that [`shutil.copy2()` can't copy all file metadata](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html), so if that happens it's like doing `cp -p` and then `rm`, I gather.

Comment: Be aware: shutil.move in Python 2.7.3 fails if the destination already exists. So if that is possible, either catch the error, or manually remove the file/dir, then do the move.

Answer (score 132):

After Python 3.4, you can also use `pathlib`'s class `Path` to move file.

```py
from pathlib import Path

Path("path/to/current/file.foo").rename("path/to/new/destination/for/file.foo")
```

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rename

Comment: I used it recently in the form of  --> 
 `Path("path/to/current/file.foo").rename("path/to/new/destination/for/".joinpath(Path.name))`   to move all the *.LNK (shortcut) files to a DUMP directory. Worked like a charm! :D

Comment: This works perfectly, but it will fail if you want move the file from one device to another (Invalid cross-device link)

Comment: @Amar maybe this is better. `Path("path/to/current/file.foo").rename(Path("path/to/new/destination/for") / Path.name))`

Answer (score 46):

For either the `os.rename` or `shutil.move` you will need to import the module.
No `*` character is necessary to get all the files moved.

We have a folder at `/opt/awesome` called source with one file named awesome.txt.

```
in /opt/awesome
○ → ls
source
○ → ls source
awesome.txt

python 
>>> source = '/opt/awesome/source'
>>> destination = '/opt/awesome/destination'
>>> import os
>>> os.rename(source, destination)
>>> os.listdir('/opt/awesome')
['destination']
```

We used `os.listdir` to see that the folder name in fact changed.
Here's the `shutil` moving the destination back to source.

```
>>> import shutil
>>> source = '/opt/awesome/destination' 
>>> destination = '/opt/awesome/source'
>>> shutil.move(source, destination)
>>> os.listdir('/opt/awesome/source')
['awesome.txt']
```

This time I checked inside the source folder to be sure the `awesome.txt` file I created exists. It is there

Now we have moved a folder and its files from a source to a destination and back again.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html This documentation shows that you have you your parameters switched for the shutil.move method.

Comment: I used the destination and source reversed to see that the files moved from the source and then back to it.... I could see how that is unclear.

Comment: error in the example. src,dst is reversed !

Answer (score 31):

This is what I'm using at the moment:

```
import os, shutil
path = "/volume1/Users/Transfer/"
moveto = "/volume1/Users/Drive_Transfer/"
files = os.listdir(path)
files.sort()
for f in files:
    src = path+f
    dst = moveto+f
    shutil.move(src,dst)
```

---

You can also turn this into a function, that accepts a source and destination directory, making the destination folder if it doesn't exist, and moves the files.  Also allows for filtering of the src files, for example if you only want to move images, then you use the pattern `'*.jpg'`, by default, it moves everything in the directory

```
import os, shutil, pathlib, fnmatch

def move_dir(src: str, dst: str, pattern: str = '*'):
    if not os.path.isdir(dst):
        pathlib.Path(dst).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    for f in fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(src), pattern):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(src, f), os.path.join(dst, f))
```

Comment: You can easily turn this into a filtered move by using fnmatch.filter(), see my edit.
Also, its best to use `os.path.join(parent_path, filename)` instead of string concatenation to avoid cross-platform issues

Answer (score 19):

The accepted answer is not the right one, because the question is not about renaming a file into a file, but moving many files into a directory. `shutil.move` will do the work, but for this purpose `os.rename` is useless (as stated on comments) because destination must have an explicit file name.

Comment: Not useless, simply requires more work to get it to move multiple files. You can get file names with `os.path.basename(my_file_path)` and the file directories with `os.path.dirname(my_file_path)`. Additionally, it was not made very clear by the OP if he wanted to move multiple files. He mentioned moving only one file in the question, but his example code implied moving multiple files.

Answer (score 4):

Since you don't care about the return value, you can do

```py
import os
os.system("mv src/* dest/")
```

Answer (score 2):

Also possible with using `subprocess.run()` method.

```
python:
>>> import subprocess
>>> new = "/path/to/destination"
>>> old = "/path/to/new/destination"
>>> process = "mv ..{} ..{}".format(old,new)
>>> subprocess.run(process, shell=True) # do not remember, assign shell value to True.
```

This will work fine when working on Linux. Windows probably gives error since there is no mv Command.

Comment: Why to call external process when python has API for that ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21804935/how-to-use-the-mv-command-in-python-with-subprocess), using `subprocess` is another option.

Something like this:

```
subprocess.call("mv %s %s" % (source_files, destination_folder), shell=True)
```

I am curious to know the pro's and con's of this method compared to `shutil`.  Since in my case I am already using `subprocess` for other reasons and it seems to work I am inclined to stick with it.

This is dependent on the shell you are running your script in. The `mv` command is for most Linux shells (bash, sh, etc.), but would also work in a terminal like Git Bash on Windows. For other terminals you would have to change `mv` to an alternate command.

Comment: I believe this would be system dependent. I don't see `mv` being used successfully on a windows operating system.

Comment: @JoshuaSchlichting It would be more shell dependent than platform type. For example, on Windows this will work fine in a Git Bash terminal, but not using Cmd.

Comment: @LightCC Good catch! Thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer with the correct information in the final paragraph rather than a question if it's system dependent.

Answer (score 1):

This is solution, which does not enables `shell` using `mv`.

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

source = "path/to/current/file.foo", 
destination = "path/to/new/destination/for/file.foo"

p = Popen(["mv", "-v", source, destination], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
output, _ = p.communicate()
output = output.strip().decode("utf-8")
if p.returncode:
    print(f"E: {output}")
else:
    print(output)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  import os,shutil

  current_path = "" ## source path

  new_path = "" ## destination path

  os.chdir(current_path)

  for files in os.listdir():

        os.rename(files, new_path+'{}'.format(f))
        shutil.move(files, new_path+'{}'.format(f)) ## to move files from
```

different disk ex. C: --> D:

Comment: if you are using Python3.# you can use the new f-string intrerpolation: `f"{new_path}{f}"` but given that you have no static text in your string, this may be more work.... I've been trying to get into the habit of using f-strings though.

Comment: Do you mean file instead of f?