# Moving files to subdirectory programatically (without using unix mv command)

Tags: python, rename, shutil

Is it possible to move by means of os.rename or shutil.move all the files in a directory to a a subdirectory of the same directory?

For example if I have the following structure:

- Dir_1

  - File_1
  - File_2
  - subDir_1

can I get the following structure:

- Dir_1

  - subDir_1

    - File_1
    - File_2
      ?

Best.-

EDIT: In the end I solved my problem using the following code:

```
    for fname in os.listdir(src):
      if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(src, fname)):
        os.rename(os.path.join(src, fname), os.path.join(dst, fname))
```

Thanks a lot to both of you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving a file in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/moving-a-file-in-python). The only difference is that you need to traverse the filesystem, using `listdir`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python

Comment: Great! That's the link I've been looking for a while but I could not find! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this could help:

```
import shutil,os,os.path


def walk(top):
    directory = None
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top, topdown=False):
        for name in dirs:
            directory = os.path.join(root, name)
        for name in files:
            f1 = os.path.join(root, name)
            if not f1.endswith('.py') and directory:
                shutil.move(f1,directory)


walk(os.path.realpath(os.curdir))
```

I tried it with this fs tree and it works:

```
-d/
  |-s/
  |-new file.txt
  |-new file1.txt
  |-move.py
```

Comment: Here is a related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50654399/1176573) as well.