# how to move files between directories in sage 6.2

Tags: sage

I am running Sage 6.2 in Virtualbox. I cannot find any GUI in Sage notebook that allows me to move files between directories. I have searched through Sage and Virtualbox official websites but I could not find any documentation on this topic. Can anyone provide guidance?

Comment: The notebook is not really designed for this.  But you should have command line access to Sage as well in the Virtualbox solution, and that should work okay.  Knowing why you need access to multiple directories in the *notebook* would be useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sage is based on Python, so you could use `shutils.move()` to move a file.

See this stackoverflow question:
[How to move a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/moving-a-file-in-python).