# Cut and Paste a File or Directory in Python

Tags: python

I need to move a lot of data to different locations on one drive, so cutting and pasting would be much faster. Currently, I'm just using shutil.copytree and shutil.rmtree, which works but it's slow.

Is there any way to cut/paste files instead of copy/delete?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/moving-a-file-in-python

Answer (score 64, accepted):

[shutil.move()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move)

```
>>> import shutil
>>> shutil.move(source, destination)
```

[os.rename()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename)

```
>>> import os
>>> os.rename(source, destination)
```

Comment: You may want to edit your answer for one correction: You have the `source` and `destination` swapped, so it should be `shutil.move(source, destination)`.