# How to read & export certain files from a Python GUI-prompted directory?

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, image-processing, io, directory

OK guys,

I'm currently working on a file reading and processing with Python & OpenCV cs' GUI feature. The feature will prompt the user to select a directory path for a folder containing 340 JPEG images, which I labelled them as "frame1" to "frame340". Then, I want to select several frames, process them, and save the processed ones in a different directory.

My big issue is, I'm trying to get only frame87, frame164, and frame248 from this folder with 340 images, and Python just keep returning error that claimed "directory name is invalid", like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\maxwell_hamzah\Documents\Python27\imageReadBeta.py", line 25, in <module>
  imgRead = os.listdir(str(dirname) + "/frame"+ str(i) + ".jpg")
WindowsError: [Error 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:/Users/maxwell_hamzah/Documents/Python27/toby arm framed/frame87.jpg/*.*'
```

To help familiarize with the situation, here's what my work looks like:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage import color, data, restoration
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog

# first, we setup the Tkinter features for file-reading
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

# prompt user to ask about the file directory
dirname = tkFileDialog.askdirectory\
(parent=root,initialdir="/",title='Pick FRAMES directory')

X = [] # initiate an array to store read images
frameIndex = [87, 163, 248] #this index is which frames we are interested in
imgRead = ""
temp = []


# we begin to read only frame87, frame163, and frame248
for i in frameIndex:
   imgRead = os.listdir(str(dirname) + "/frame"+ str(i) + ".jpg")
   temp = cv2.imread(imgRead, -1)
   X.append(temp)
```

I'm totally stuck on how to fix this bug on especially the for loop part, where the error comes from. Python keeps freeking out on the imgRead variable claiming that the directory is invalid. Plus, I'm also wondering on how to "export" processed files to other directories (e.g. saving processed images from "My Pictures" to  "My Music")

Really appreciate your help, guys.

Maxwell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last block, you call a method to list files, which is expecting a directory, but you pass it a file path. That's a bug, and actually you don't need that here in the first place:

```
for i in frameIndex:
   imgRead = "{0}/frame{1}.jpg".format(dirname, i)
   temp = cv2.imread(imgRead, -1)
   X.append(temp)
```

As to moving files in Python, that's a pretty classic need, there's plenty of doc out there. [One example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/moving-a-file-in-python).

Comment: Gee, thanks. I even didn't realize if that's bug :p

But many thanks for blowing my mind in this case :)