# Saving files based on filename to individual folders

Tags: python

I have a list of 480 files and I would like to save them to 80 folders based on their filenames.  Examples of the filenames are:

```
LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band1.tif
LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band2.tif
LT50300282007136PAC01_sr_band1.tif
LT50300282007136PAC01_sr_band2.tif
LT50300282002138LGS01_sr_band1.tif
LT50300282002138LGS01_sr_band2.tif
```

I want to save files that have matching characters in a slice of the first 21 characters [0:21] into folders that have that same name.  For example:

```
LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band1.tif
LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band2.tif
```

would go into folder titled `LT50300281984137PAC00`

and

```
LT50300282007136PAC01_sr_band1.tif
LT50300282007136PAC01_sr_band2.tif
```

would go into folder titled `LT50300282007136PAC01`

I have already created the folders using this code:

```
import arcpy
import os
#pathway where there are only 80 .tif files, one for each landsat scene
arcpy.env.workspace=r'F:\Sheyenne\Atmospherically Corrected Landsat\hank_masked\Band 1'
#list of rasters in above pathway
list1 = arcpy.ListRasters("*.tif")
#output save pathway
mainpath=r'F:\Sheyenne\Atmospherically Corrected Landsat\Individual Scenes\Main'

#create folder for each landsatscene containing first 21 characters
for raster in list1:
    rasterName=raster[0:21]
    if raster.startswith(rasterName.split("_")[0]):
        final_path=os.path.join(mainpath,rasterName)
        os.makedirs(final_path)
```

and now I want to take every file that has 'band' in the name like I showed above and store it in the correct folders but this is where I am stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import arcpy, os

original_path = r'F:\Sheyenne\Atmospherically Corrected Landsat\hank_masked\Band 1'
#pathway where there are only 80 .tif files, one for each landsat scene
arcpy.env.workspace=original_path
#list of rasters in above pathway
list1 = arcpy.ListRasters("*.tif")
#output save pathway
main_path=r'F:\Sheyenne\Atmospherically Corrected Landsat\Individual Scenes\Main'

#create folder for each landsatscene containing first 21 characters
for raster in list1:

    source_path = os.path.join(original_path, raster)
    dir_name=split("_")[0]
    destination_path=os.path.join(main_path, dir_name)

    if not os.path.isdir(destination_path):
        os.makedirs(destination_path)

    destination_path = os.path.join(destination_path, raster)

    if not os.path.exists(destination_path):
        os.rename(source_path, destination_path)
```

Comment: what does `dir_name` represent in this example?

Comment: dir_name is the folder name that may or may not need to be created gets added to the end of the destination path

Answer (score 1):

Run this script in the same directory with your `.tif` files. It assumes that you already have the directories, as you mentioned in the question.

```
import glob
import os

for source in glob.glob("*band*.tif"):
    target = os.path.join( source[:21], source )
    os.rename(source, target)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already created the folder, you should be able to use the os.rename command (as shown in the link) inside the loop: [How to move a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/moving-a-file-in-python)

```
# Create a var to store the original path
original_path = r'F:\Sheyenne\Atmospherically Corrected Landsat\hank_masked\Band 1'
arcpy.env.workspace= original_path

#list of rasters in above pathway
list1 = arcpy.ListRasters("*.tif")

#output save pathway
mainpath=r'F:\Sheyenne\Atmospherically Corrected Landsat\Individual Scenes\Main'

#create folder for each landsatscene containing first 21 characters
for raster in list1:
    rasterName=raster[0:21]
    if raster.startswith(rasterName.split("_")[0]):
        final_path=os.path.join(mainpath,rasterName)
        os.makedirs(final_path)
        # create a path for the new file
        new_file = os.path.join(final_path, 'new_file_name.tif')
        # create a path for the old file
        old_file = os.path.join(original_path, raster)
        # rename (move) the old file to the new file
        os.rename(old_file, new_file)
```