# For file in directories, rename file to directoryname

Tags: python

I have let's say 5 directories, let's call them dir1, dir2, dir3, dir4, dir5.

These are all in the current directory. Each of them contains 1 files called title.mkv. I want to rename the files to the directory name they are in, ie the file title.mkv in dir1, I want to rename to dir1.mkv.

I also want to then move the file to another folder. What python tools do I need for this besides os and glob?

Comment: Possibly `shutil.move()` if you don't want to use `os.rename()`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/moving-a-file-in-python

Answer (score 0):

If you have the full filename and directory, to rename the files, you can use

```
import os
f_name = 'E:/temp/nuke.mkv'
# Removes '/' at the end of string
while f_name.endswith('/'):
    f_name = f_name[:-1]
# Generates List Containing Directories and File Name
f_name_split = f_name.split('/')
f_path = ''
# Iterates Through f_name_split, adding directories to new_f_path
for i in range(len(f_name_split)-1):
    f_path += f_name_split[i] + '/'
# Makes New Name Based On Folder Name
new_name = f_name_split[-2] + '.mkv'
# Gets The Old File Name
f_name = f_name_split[-1]
# Renames The File
os.rename(f_path + f_name, f_path + new_name)
```

To go through all of the directories, you could do it recursively, have the system output it to a file [windows: dir /s /b /a > file.txt], or use os.walk. To move a file, you can use os.rename(source, destination)

Answer (score 0):

The following should work, although you will have problems if there is more than one file per source folder:

```
import os 

source_folder = r"c:\my_source_folder"
target_folder = r"c:\target_folder"

for directory_path, dirs, files in os.walk(source_folder):

    # Current directory name
    directory = os.path.split(directory_path)[1]

    # Ensure only MKV files are processed
    files = [file for file in files if os.path.splitext(file)[1].lower() == '.mkv']

    # Rename each file

    for file in files:
        source = os.path.join(directory_path, file)
        target = os.path.join(target_folder, directory + ".mkv")

        try:
            os.rename(source, target)
        except OSError:
            print "Failed to rename: {} to {}".format(source, target)
```

It will search all sub folders from the source folder and use the current folder name for the target name.

Comment: `os.rename` doesn't work across filesystems. `shutil.move` does.

Answer (score 0):

The following function uses `shutil.move`, which moves across filesystem and has overwrite protection in case destination file exists.  File name can be relative.

```
from os.path import basename, dirname, isfile, abspath, splitext
from shutil import move

def rename_to_dirname_and_move(name, dst, overwrite=False, verbose=False):

    """renames 'name' to its directory name, keeping its extension
       intact and moves to 'dst' directory across filesystem
    """
    if not isfile(name):
        raise ValueError("{} is not a file or doesn't exist".format(name))

    abs_name = abspath(name)
    dir_name = basename(dirname(abs_name))
    new_name = '{}{}'.format(dir_name, splitext(name)[1])
    dst_name = os.path.join(dst, new_name)

    if not overwrite and isfile(dst_name):
        raise OSError('file {} exists'.format(dst_name))

    try:
        move(abs_name, dst_name)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Can't move {} to {}, error: {}".format(abs_name, dst_name,e))
    else:
        if verbose:
            print('Moved {} to {}'.format(abs_name, dst_name))
```