# Python - How to move the file after complete writing

Tags: python, linux

How to set python to move the file after complete writing in the server ?

Below is my same to lock the file after complete writing, but it does'nt work in Linux server.

```
try:
   fcntl.lockf(file2,fcntl.LOCK_EX|fcntl.LOCK_NB)
   print "Yes Locked"
   time.sleep(20)
except:
    print "No Lock"

file.close()
```

Any right suggestion ? Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You could use the os.rename method:

```
import os
os.rename('oldPath/Name', 'newPath/Name')
```

Check out this answer for additional info:
[How to move a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python)