# Python 2.7 - Filter files with a specific string in filename inside a directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'd like to move a file from one directory to another by filtering the filename with a specific string

Seems like fnmatch or glob can do this but I can't figure it out

In the example below, how could python move only the file *test_High_Quality.mb* to another directory using the filter *High_Quality* in the filename

```
>>> import os    
>>> myPath = "C:\Project"    
>>> os.listdir('myPath')    
>>> ['test_Draft.txt', 'test_Mid_Quality.txt', 'test_High_Quality.txt']
```

Comment: You want everything with `High_Quality` in the filename?

Comment: Exactly, if the filename contains High_Quality, then I'd like to move the file to another directory. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach using `filter`:

```
high_quality = filter(lambda fname: 'High_Quality' in fname, os.listdir('myPath'))
```

Convert `high_quality` to a list or set if you want to iterate over it more than once (`filter` returns a generator).

Comment: I'll study to understand what is happening in this line of code as I'm not familiar with the lambda function. This is going to be very useful for my script. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

To filter with file names "High_Quality"

```
[d for d in os.listdir('myPath') if 'High_Quality' in d]
```

For moving to other directory, follow this solution [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python)

Comment: This solution is going to useful too. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) function to search for filenames matching patterns.

```
> from glob import glob
> glob("C:\Project\*High_Quality*")

['test_High_Quality.txt']
```

See the linked documentation for further details.

Comment: This is what I get when I try the code above: ['C:/Project\\test_High_Quality.txt']. May be the '\\' could cause a problem, no?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.filter) method from `fnmatch` module for the same purpose, very straightforward application, just make sure you build the correct pattern to your needs, like in your case matching all string including `High_Quality` :

```
>>> l = ['test_Draft.txt', 'test_Mid_Quality.txt', 'test_High_Quality.txt']
>>> 
>>> import fnmatch
>>> 
>>> fnmatch.filter(l, "*High_Quality*")
['test_High_Quality.txt']
```

Comment: I didn't think to store all the filenames in a list before applying a filter. Very good trick. Thank you very much

Comment: @ADMMTL, There is no trick about this solution, except for using elementary programming technique with Python, you seem to be very new, it will become common-sense to you after practicing more with this language :)

Answer (score 0):

If you stick this file in an empty directory you can see how glob will work just fine for you. You just need `*High_Quality*` as your glob pattern:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import glob
import os


filenames = [
    'fnord.txt',
    'fizzy.txt',
    'test_Low_Quality.txt',
    'test_Mid_Quality.txt',
    'test_High_Quality.txt',
    'test_High_Quality_one.txt',
    'test_High_Quality_two.txt',
]

for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, 'w'): pass
print('Files:')
print('\t', '\n\t'.join(os.listdir(os.curdir)), sep='')
print('Files matching *High_Quality*:')
print('\t', '\n\t'.join(glob.glob('*High_Quality*')), sep='')
```

Comment: This script is a little bit advanced for my skills but I'll study it very carefully. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

## Filter with glob module:

### Import glob

```
import glob
```

### Pattern

```
pattern='*High_Quality*'

files=glob.glob(pattern)
```

### Wild Cards:

```
files=glob.glob("data/*")

print(files)


Out:

['data/ks_10000_0', 'data/ks_1000_0', 'data/ks_100_0', 'data/ks_100_1',
'data/ks_100_2', 'data/ks_106_0', 'data/ks_19_0', 'data/ks_200_0', 'data/ks_200_1', 
'data/ks_300_0', 'data/ks_30_0', 'data/ks_400_0', 'data/ks_40_0', 'data/ks_45_0', 
'data/ks_4_0', 'data/ks_500_0', 'data/ks_50_0', 'data/ks_50_1', 'data/ks_60_0', 
'data/ks_82_0', 'data/ks_lecture_dp_1', 'data/ks_lecture_dp_2']
```

### Fiter extension .txt:

```
files = glob.glob("/home/ach/*/*.txt")
```

### A single character

```
glob.glob("/home/ach/file?.txt")
```

### Number Ranges

```
glob.glob("/home/ach/*[0-9]*")
```

### Alphabet Ranges

```
glob.glob("/home/ach/[a-c]*")
```