# How to move a file specified in text file based on condition using Python

Tags: python

I have a text file as below.

```
4b64dac0d3b4592143368e6c2d676039165b6159  Detections: -1
0e00854b6b9e431ce1fe56b9bcebdb6b8f088012  Detections: 0
1c1fc6283eb75cc1fd2885a81d43843009ebba77  Detections: 14
2e19a1b2e451e799b2feaba39148cfd2740de8e2  Detections: 5
3a0761b29c55135122fcdb2ebb72519306ea4b35  Detections: 1
```

And Five files named as mentioned above in one location:

In that, i want to move file to specific folder based on detection Condition.
The condition are: If detection is greater than Zero means, it move to folder name "found". If detection is lesser and equal to Zero means , it move to folder name "Not found".

Result would be:

In Found folder,

```
1c1fc6283eb75cc1fd2885a81d43843009ebba77
2e19a1b2e451e799b2feaba39148cfd2740de8e2
3a0761b29c55135122fcdb2ebb72519306ea4b35
```

These files will be moved

and In Not Found Folder,

```
4b64dac0d3b4592143368e6c2d676039165b6159
0e00854b6b9e431ce1fe56b9bcebdb6b8f088012
```

These files will be moved.

Can anyone could help me through done this?

i have tried like:

```
with open('D:\SHARE\Check\check.txt') as infile:
  for line in infile:
    if condition:
      Detections: 0
      next(infile)
```

I don't know how to check condition and move file based on that

Comment: Could you provide paths to the files?

Comment: D:\SHARE\Check . In this location i have five files and one text file.

Comment: Please provide you code or attempts.

Comment: Add your code and additional details to your question, not the comments

Comment: What do you think `Detections: 0` does? It's not valid python, what is it supposed to mean? What is the `next` for?

Comment: No, I want to move files based on  detection conditon specified in text file.

Comment: That's what i am saying . i'm not good at python.Pls tell me how to check detection condition

Comment: SO is not really a 'write my code for me' service.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the condition this way:

```
with open('D:\SHARE\Check\check.txt','r') as checkfile:
    content = checkfile.readlines()

content = [x.strip() for x in content] # here is the content of your file without empty elements

for i in content:
    file_line = i.split(' ')
    if int(file_line[2].strip()) > 0: # if condition is greater that zero
        #move to found
    else: #if condition is zero or less
        #move to not found
```

And here you can find how to move the file: [How to move a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python)