# Will the file be removed from the current folder?

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out the best way to move one file from a specified folder into another specified folder using python. I managed to find two different ways to do that.

`os.rename("path/to/current/filename.txt","path/to/new/desination/for/filename.txt")`

`shutil.move("path/to/current/filename.txt", "path/to/new/destination/for/file.txt")`

Which method is better to use in order to move the file to the destination folder and delete any duplication files that might occur there? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move a file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python)

Comment: do `help(os.rename)` and `help(shutil.move)` in python console
so you can see why you better stick with `move` and not `rename` (at least if you don't take into account their names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will rename it, which means the original file will be 'moved' to the destination. If you doubt it, just try it out with a test file

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It will be moved (not copied) to the new destination. os.rename() is just like mv in shell. It will rename/move the file.

you can test it will a custom script also.

```
import os

os.rename("src", "dst")
```

Answer (score 0):

[os.rename](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename) moves the file from source to destination folder!

It is similar to [mv](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mv) shell command

If you want to copy a file, you can use [shutil.copyfile()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) - [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python)

```
from shutil import copyfile    
copyfile(src, dst)
```

Happy Coding!