# python moving files based on extensions?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I improve this python code. I want to add a list here which includes all the extension and with the help of the list, I want to search for "src" directory for extensions and move them to the destination.

```
import shutil
import glob
import os

dest_dir = "/home/xxxx/Software/"
dest_dir2 = "/home/flyingpizza/Pictures/"

for file in glob.glob(r'/home/xxxxx/Downloads/*.pdf'):
    print (file)
    shutil.move(file,dest_dir)

for file in glob.glob(r'/home/xxxx/Downloads/*.docx'):
    print(file)
    shutil.move(file, dest_dir)

for file in glob.glob(r'/home/xxxx/Downloads/*.exe'):
    print(file)
    shutil.move(file,dest_dir)

for file in glob.glob(r'/home/xxxx/Downloads/*.jpg'):
    print(file)
    shutil.move(file,dest_dir2)

for file in glob.glob(r'/home/xxxxx/Downloads/*.torrent'):
    print(file)
    os.remove(file)
```

Comment: Maybe add `from __future__ import print_function` at the top, so this code really works on the tagged python-2.7 ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a dict of locations and extensions, for example `{'/home/xxx/Pictures': ['jpg','png','gif'], ...}` Where I use the "keys" as destinations and the values are lists of extensions for each destination.

```
source = '/home/xxx/randomdir/'
mydict = {
    '/home/xxx/Pictures': ['jpg','png','gif'],
    '/home/xxx/Documents': ['doc','docx','pdf','xls']
}
for destination, extensions in mydict.items():
    for ext in extensions:
        for file in glob.glob(source + '*.' + ext):
            print(file)
            shutil.move(file, destination)
```

While Fabre's solution is good, you would have to repeat his double-loop solution for every destination folder, whereas here you have a triple-loop that does everything, as long as you give it a proper `dict`

Also a word of advice, if you write code that looks so repetitive, like yours do, be sure there is a way to make it simpler, either with a loop or a function that takes arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the help that works! I added "os.replace(file, destination)" in your code to replace any existing file.

Comment: Great solution and nice bit of advice as well - upvoted! I love using glob for file handling. Another thing to remember for file handling is that moving a file and renaming a file are almost always the exact same processes.I say this because @Ofer-Sadan code can be used to do either.

Answer (score 2):

Another extensible solution

```
import os
import shutil

dir1 = "/home/xxxx/Software/"
dir2 = "/home/flyingpizza/Pictures/"

def moveto(dst):
    return lambda src: shutil.move(src, dst)

action = {
    'pdf': moveto(dir1),
    'docx': moveto(dir1),
    'exe': moveto(dir1),
    'jpg': moveto(dir2),
    'torrent': os.remove,
}

src_dir = '/home/xxxxx/Downloads'
for file in os.listdir(src_dir):
    ext = os.path.splitext(file)[1][1:]
    if ext in action:
        action[ext](os.path.join(src_dir, file))
```

Answer (score 1):

with a double loop and generate the pattern using `format`:

```
for ext in ["docx","pdf","exe","jpg"]:
    for file in glob.glob('/home/xxxxx/Downloads/*.{}'.format(ext)):
        print (file)
        shutil.move(file,dest_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the following code and save as ".py" **in the same folder** with the file you want to separate by extension, then run the python file.

```
from os import *
import shutil

def makeDir(DirectoryName):
    if path.exists(DirectoryName)==False: mkdir(DirectoryName)

def movefile(item):
    extName=path.splitext(item.name)[1][1:]
    try:
        if extName != '':
            makeDir(extName)
            shutil.move(item, extName)
        elif extName == '' and item.name[0][0]!='.':
            makeDir('NoExt')
            shutil.move(item, 'NoExt')
        else:
            makeDir('NoName')
            shutil.move(item, 'NoName')
    except:
        None

chdir(path.dirname(__file__))

for file in scandir(getcwd()):
    movefile(file) if path.isfile(file) and file.name != path.basename(__file__) else None
```