# How to move the differing and absent files while comparing two directories?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an archived folder, named "dir1".
I have an new data folder, named "dir2".
I have a differences folder, named "dir3".
The data are jpgs, there are no sub folders.

```
dir1
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg

dir2
1.jpg (edited file)
2.jpg (edited file)
3.jpg (same file as in dir1)
4.jpg (same file as in dir1)
5.jpg (new file)
6.jpg (new file)
```

I need to move the new, missing, edited and differing files to dir3.
The result would be:

```
dir3
1.jpg
2.jpg
5.jpg
6.jpg
```

Here is what i have:

```
from filecmp import dircmp

dcmp = dircmp('dir1', 'dir2')

def main(dcmp):
    for name in dcmp.diff_files, dcmp.right_only:
        print (name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(dcmp)
```

The result is:

```
['2.jpg', '1.JPG']
['6.jpg', '5.jpg']
```

Insted of "print", how do i move these to dir3.
I've tried "shutil" and "os.rename", but i cant get it to work.


Information from "filecmp" and "dircmp".

```
import filecmp

filecmp.dircmp('dir1', 'dir2').report()
```

The result is:

```
diff dir1 dir2
Only in dir2 : ['5.jpg', '6.jpg']
Identical files : ['3.JPG', '4.JPG']
Differing files : ['1.JPG', '2.jpg']
```

This is just fyi.

Comment: Why not just use `rsync` and be done with it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reference to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8858026/3717717) on how to create a new directory and move files to it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you already have the part to make the list of files that you want to move.

```
import shutil

for file in file_list:
    shutil.move(file, dir3) # shutil.copy if you want
```

Note: `file` should be the path to the file and `dir3` can be a directory or file path if you want to change the name or the like.

Comment: I did this, and i get an error:
from filecmp import dircmp
import shutil

def print_diff_files(dcmp):
    for name in dcmp.diff_files, dcmp.right_only:
        shutil.move(name, 'dir3')

dcmp = dircmp('dir1', 'dir2') 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print_diff_files(dcmp)

Comment: You're passing arguments for path that aren't working.  Try being more explicit in the path.  e.g. instead of `name`, `os.path.join(r'C:\user\dir2', name)`.  It's most likely an issue with your assumption of relative path.  Also, your example is super convoluted with unnecessary functions etc, please try to reduce it to the relevant information.

Comment: I've change question to be less convoluted, i didnt want to leave something out... I need this optimal for comparing large amounts of data.