# Move Certain Files from One Directory to Another - Python

Tags: python, list, file, directory

All,

I need to move file from one directory to another but I don't want to move all the files in that directory just the text files that begin with `'pws'`. A `list` of all the files in the directory is:

```
['pws1.txt', 'pws2.txt', 'pws3.txt', 'pws4.txt', 'pws5.txt', 'x.txt', 'y.txt']
```

As stated, I want to move the `'pws*'` files to another directory but not the x and y text files. What I want to do is remove all elements the `list` that does not begin with `'pws'`.  My code is below:

```
loc = 'C:\Test1'
dir = os.listdir(loc)

#print dir

for i in dir:
#print i
x = 'pws*'
if i != x:
dir.remove(i)
print dir
```

The output does not keep what I want instead

It removes the x text file from the `list` and the even number ones but retains the y text files.

What am I doing wrong. How can I make a `list` of only the files that start with `'pws'` and remove the  text files that do not begin with `'pws'`.

Keep in mind I might have a `list` that has 1000 elements and several hundreds of those elements will start with `'pws'` while those that don't begin with it, couple of hundreds, will need to be removed.

Everyone's help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `list-comprehension` to re-create the `list` as the following:

```
dir = [i for i in dir if i.startswith('pws')]
```

or better yet, define that at start:

```
loc = 'C:\\Test1'
dir = [i for i in os.listdir(loc) if i.startswith('pws')]
print dir
```

**Explanation:**

When you use `x = 'pws*'` and then check for `if i == x`, you are comparing if the element `i` is equal to `'pws*'`, so a better way is to use `str.startswith()` built in method that will check if the `string` starts with the provided `substring`. So in your `loop` you can use `if i.startswith('pws')` or you can use `list-comprehension` as I mentioned above which is a more pythonic approach.

Comment: Thank you. I ran the edited code, but I keep getting syntax error related to "for" in dir = [i for i in ....

Comment: @duranil change this line `loc = 'C:\Test1'` to `loc = 'C:\\Test1'` because you need to escape backlashes

Answer (score 0):

To move a file:
[How to move a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python)
You can use os.rename(origin,destination)

```
origin = r'C:\users\JohnDoe\Desktop'
destination = r'C:\users\JohnDoe\Desktop\Test'
startswith_ = 'pws'
```

And then go ahead and do a list comprehension

```
# Move files
[os.rename(os.path.join(origin,i),os.path.join(destination,i)) for i in os.listdir(origin) if i.startswith(startswith_)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `glob`. This gives you a list of files in a directory without all the `listdir` calls and substring matching:

```
import glob,os
for f in glob.glob('/tmp/foo/pws*'):
    os.rename(f, '/tmp/bar/%s'%(os.path.basename(f)))
```

Edit 1: Here's your original code, simplified with a `glob`, and a new variable loc2 defined to be the place to move them to:

```
import os,glob
loc = 'C:\Test1'
loc2 = 'C:\Test2'
files = glob.glob('%s\pws*'%(loc))

for i in files:
    os.rename(i,'%s\%s'%(loc2,os.path.basename(i)))
```

Comment: @duranil, the code certainly does _something_. What part isn't working? Does the glob provide the list of files you expect? Does the os.rename not move them to the destination?