# zip a folder and store zipped file into another folder in python

Tags: python, directory, store, zip

I am zipping a folder in python like

```
mypath = "c:\Test\mypath"
foldername = "mydata"
zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(foldername + '.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
zipdir(mypath, zipf)
zipf.close()
```

the output of zipped file mydata.zip is located at mypath "c:\Test\mypath\mydata.zip"
But i want mydata.zip file into another folder like "c:\Test\mypath\anotherfolder\mydata.zip"

Please help me to do achieve this.

Comment: os.rename() or shutil.move() 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python

Comment: or specify the absolute filepath to `ZipFile()`

Answer (score 0):

The zip file is created in the current working directory. that is "c:\Test\mypath"
To achieve my requirement, I changed the current working directory using os.chdir() as  "c:\Test\mypath\anotherfolder" and got the zip file in the same location

```
mypath = "c:\Test\mypath"
foldername = "mydata"
anotherpath = "c:\Test\mypath\anotherfolder"
os.chdir(anotherpath)
zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(foldername + '.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
zipdir(mypath, zipf)
zipf.close()
```