# Rename multiple images and save into another folder with python

Tags: python

I have 100 images in a folder and I want to rename all of them. For example, Car.1.jpg, Car.2.jpg,Car.3.jpg so on and save them into another folder. I wrote the code which renames all the images as I want but it saves in the same folder which images exist. I want to rename all images and keep the original image name in the directory and copy renamed images into another directory.

```
import os
from tqdm import tqdm

path = './training_data/car/'

def image_rename():
    cnt = 1
    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(path)):
        if os.path.isfile(path+img):
            filename, file_extention = os.path.splitext(path+img)
            os.rename(os.path.join(path, img), os.path.join(path, 
                       str('car.') + str(cnt) + file_extention))
       cnt +=1

image_rename()
```

Comment: `os.chdir` will change the working directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python)

Comment: Use the full path instead of the relative path (e.g. `path = '/home/armin/training_data/car/`)

Comment: `os.rename` is a `mv` use `shutil.copy` instead

Comment: @djangoliv Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should try using [shutil.move()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move)

```
import shutil
shutil.move("path/to/current/file.foo", "path/to/new/destination/for/file.foo")
```

Comment: Its moving after rename, I dont want to move my images after rename. I mean, I want to keep my images and names in the folder and copy images into another folder with the name which i want

Comment: Found the answer, I had to use shutil.copy("path/to/current/file.foo", "path/to/new/destination/for/file.foo")

Answer (score 1):

Add a variable `output_path` pointing to the folder to which you want to export the files, then use this variable in the seconde argument of `os.rename()`, like this :

```
import os
from tqdm import tqdm

path = './training_data/car/'
output_path = './training_data/output_folder/'

def image_rename():
    cnt = 1
    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(path)):
        if os.path.isfile(path+img):
            filename, file_extention = os.path.splitext(path+img)
            os.rename(os.path.join(path, img), os.path.join(output_path, 
                       str('car.') + str(cnt) + file_extention))
       cnt +=1

image_rename()
```

Make sure to create the output folder in your system (by using `mkdir`, for example).

Comment: I did this one before, but my problem is after rename, all my images move to output_path. I want to keep my images and their name in the folder which exists and rename images into another folder