# How do I copy and move another folder or dir in python?

Tags: python

I want to copy and move (or paste) the file into folder like backup program. 
But I don't know what to do :( 
I tried `shutil.copy2(filename, example)` but I couldn't use it on another environment because I didn't know A.

```
import os 
import shutil 
from tkinter import *
from filedialog import *

def func_open() :
    global filename
    filename = askopenfilename(parent = window, filetypes = (("SMI", "*.smi"), ("All", "*")))
    A = os.path.basename(filename)
```

I used tkinter function. and func_open is works by pressing button.

Comment: What have you tried or researched so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python), and/or [How to copy a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

copy:

```
from shutil import copy
copy(source,destination)
```

move:

```
from shutil import move
move(source,destination)
```