# My python script deletes files instead of renaming them

Tags: python-3.x

I think I have managed to get this resolved.Wrote a Pyhon script to rename files, but it deletes them instead of renaming them. What am I doing wrong here? I have figured out the issue with renaming. Can someone tell me why the below if statement is failing now to pull only the files that start with the word "New"?

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import os
import datetime
import glob

now = datetime.datetime.now()
#store date in string variable
dateStr = str(now.strftime('%Y%m%d-'))
src = r"C:\Users\username\Downloads"

for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(src, '*.txt')):
    #Grab the basename
    fileName = os.path.basename(file)
    newName =  src + "\\" + dateStr + fileName
    #THIS if statement does not work
    #if fileName.startswith("New"):
    os.rename(file, newName)
    print(newName)
```

Can anyone advise why the above if-statement does not work?

Comment: Doesn't `os.rename('c:/foo/bar/Newwibble.txt', '20180713-Newwibble.txt')` move the file to the current working directory, not to `c:/foo/bar/` as hoped?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python)

Comment: @KenY-N No just renaming the files then will finish the script to move them to another directory

Comment: My issue is about renaming the files NOT MOVING THEM

Comment: You are using the path in part of the command, but not in the other part of the command. I would guess all your files are at `C:\dateStr...`? Try `newName = src + r"\" + dateStr + head + tail`. And why split then just `+` back together if you aren't inserting the dateStr between...?

Comment: updated my script as above, but still having issues

Comment: Deleted this comment

Comment: Please describe how you have updated it, because as Marichyasana points out, you have introduced a new bug. Please also describe your problem in more detail than "still having issues". Finally, you should check the return value for `os.rename()` to see if any errors occur.

Comment: I have made it work now by commenting out this line if file.startswith("New"):

Answer (score 0):

( I ran this on  my computer so the filenames don't match yours)

in the for statement the variable 'file' is a full path with filename something like

```
C:\Users\Philip\Downloads\PROGIDS-ON-THIS-COMPUTER.txt
```

and is not changed
so when the 'if' statement checks to see if it starts with "New" it never matches

```
you probably want to change to use 'fileName' instead
```

Comment: The code initially use `filename`, but it's since been edited, which is one reason it is not advised to edit code in a question too drastically, or at least without noting the change.