# not able to move file python

Tags: python, mv, python-watchdog

There have been some similar solutions given before but none seem to work for me.

code:

```
def watch_dir(self, prefix, dest):
    before = dict([(f, None) for f in os.listdir(self.data_dir)])
    while 1:
        time.sleep(5)
        after = dict([(f, None) for f in os.listdir(self.data_dir)])
        new_files = [f for f in after if not f in before and f.startswith(prefix)]
        before = new_files
        for f in new_files:
            os.system('mv {f} {dest}'.format(f=f, dest=dest))
```

When I print new_files I get -> `('new_files = ', ['sample.tsv'])`

but the `mv` command gives this error:
`mv: cannot stat 'sample.tsv': No such file or directory`

Can someone help me understand what could be going wrong here?!

Thanks!

Comment: The error says it couldn't find the file `sample.tsv`. Try to provide an absolute path to the file, this should fix it.  Also, there are better ways of moving a file in python. Take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. don't use `os.system` ever - to run subprocesses in python, use the `subprocess` module.
2. even using `subprocess` is too much in this case, as you want to move a file so you can just use `shutil.move()` to do the same without invoking a separate process.
3. `os.listdir` returns only the filenames without the path, so you have to add that yourself to be able to find the file: `os.path.join(self.datadir, f)`
4. to watch directories/files efficiently without checking them every 5 seconds, you can use the [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify) module - it uses a efficient system api to watch the directory and will call your function when it changes, no polling involved.