# How do you use the os.rename() function in python 3?

Tags: python, python-os

I'm trying to rename the file names and extensions of all the files in a directory and move them to a new directory. I've read multiple post on how to do it but for some reason I haven't been successful and I've been stuck on this for 3 days now and feel like I'm doing something careless. Somebody get me on track please. 
This is the latest way I've been trying.

```
import os

previousName = 'Macintosh HD⁩/⁨Users⁩/⁨kunductor/⁨Desktop⁩/⁨folder3/windeffect.asd'

newName = 'Macintosh HD⁩/Users⁩/kunductor⁩/Desktop⁩/folder4/wind.wav'

os.rename(previousName,newName)
```

When I run the code above I get the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rename.py", line 7, in <module>
    os.rename(previousName,newName)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

If it matters, I'm  using macOS Mojave, version 10.14.2.

Comment: [Looks like](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename) you'd need to use the `src_dir_fd` and `dst_dir_fd` parameters to specify the path for the file you're renaming, if I'm understanding those correctly. ...Actually, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8858026/2617068) says what you're doing should work. What doesn't work when you try that?

Comment: You might want to construct the file names with `os.path.join()`.  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join

Comment: `Macintosh HD` is almost certainly not supposed to be the first path component. `/Users/kunductor/...` seems more likely to be correct.

Comment: i tried that too. thats how i was doing it the first couple of days. i dont know why its not working but it looks like im going to have to just spend a day and a half doing this manually until my light bulb moment.

Comment: @TheKunductor quick sanity check to see if the path is correct, just do `os.path.exists(my_path)` and if it's False, you've not got the right path.

Answer (score 0):

I tried replicating the same using Python 3 on Mojave 10.14.2. Use the paths starting from `'/Users'`, and don't include `Macintosh HD`. The code runs perfectly when both `folder3` and `folder4` exist. I got a similar error when `folder4` was removed, and the error message also specified the paths I passed as parameters.

If that's what you're experiencing, ensure that the directory you're trying to move the file to exists before calling `os.rename`. This can be done in Python itself by using the `os.mkdir` method. Since it throws an error if the directory already exists, you can check that by using the `os.path.exists` method.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code that worked. I think the problem was that i was trying to change a non-audio file to a .wav and the system was rejecting it.

```
import os 

# Function to rename multiple files 
def main(): 
    i = 0

    for filename in os.listdir('/Users/vfloyd/Desktop/uu/'): 
        dst ="Kick" + str(i) + ".wav"
        src = '/Users/vfloyd/Desktop/uu/'+ filename 
        dst ='/Users/vfloyd/Desktop/newD/'+ dst 

        # rename() function will 
        # rename all the files 
        os.rename(src, dst) 
        i += 1

# Driver Code 
if __name__ == '__main__': 

    # Calling main() function 
    main()
```