# How to move files from a directory to another?

Tags: python, windows

This is my Python script:

```
import json
import csv
import glob
import os
import shlex
import subprocess

os.chdir('C:/ck-master/target')
path='C:/Users/AQ42770/Desktop/congress-android'
for n in range(0,100):

    path1= path+"/"+str(n)

    cmd='java -jar ck-0.3.2-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar "%s"'
    cmd = cmd % (path)
    args = shlex.split(cmd)
    p = subprocess.Popen(args)
```

It returns for me 4 CSV files in directory `C:\ck-master\target`.

The problem is that each time it crushes the 4 CSV files and returns the last result. My expectation is that for each iteration it should move files to another folder and it should name them from 0 to 99.

Comment: argh this code would need a big refactoring, sorry to say. Don't use string + shlex, pass a list directly. Plus don't `chdir` use `cwd` in subprocess call, plus `os.path.join` instead of adding path strings.

Comment: You should be able to use `os.rename`.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre why I should not use string + shlex and what do u mean by  pass a list directly ?

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python

Answer (score 0):

I will answer briefly, cause the question is duplicate.
Task is done with python or cmd directly.
1) Find files in the directory. For example using **os.listdir()** or **glob.glob()** methods
2) Copy them using **shututil** [How do I copy a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python) or write copy urself. It's simple - jost open the file and write it to new destination with a new name. 
or move - [How to move a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python)
3) Success