# Moving files according to a csv file

Tags: python, file, csv

Assuming I have 2 folders - Images A, and Images B, and there's a bunch of images in each folder. These folders have the following structure:

```
Images A
-- 1111,jpg
-- 2222.jpg
-- 3333.jpg
-- 4444.jpg
-- 5555.jpg

Images B
-- 6666,jpg
-- 7777.jpg
-- 8888.jpg
-- 99999.jpg
```

Plus, I have a csv with a list of image names. Thing is, I need to move those images ( from imagesA/B) to a new empty folder, let's call it - New Folder. Question is how do I do it?

The csv file looks like this:

```
blabla/blabla2/blabla3/2222.jpg
blabla/blabla2/blabla3/7777.jpg
```

(Needless to mention that I don't have all the blabla directories, I should use split and forget about all the blabla).

Comment: Can the image names be anything, or is it just the 1111...9999.jpg?

Comment: Consider the csv module

Comment: Could be anything, it's just for simplicity.

Comment: You can use `os.path.split()` to separate the directory from the filenames.

Comment: I also need to move the right files from. images A and images B to "New folder".

Comment: What's your problem exactly? Just use `os.path.basename()` on each csv line, and `shutil.move()` for example to move these files to the new folder.

Comment: this might help [how to move files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python)

Comment: I need to know more about how your files are organized. It is unclear if the A/B folder are in the blabla/blabla2/blabla3 folders.

Comment: Like I mentioned, there's no blabla folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `csv` and module can help.

Assuming the .csv file is a simple list of relative paths of image files, that is of the form:

```
1111.png
2222.png
...
```

The `csv.reader` method allows you to read each row of the csv sheet. Then, you use `os.rename([past], [new])` to check if that file is in folder `A` or `B` and then write it to the New Folder. Be careful of `FileExistsError` in case of name clashes. Here is the sample code.

```
import csv
import os

with open('csvmove.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    linereader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in linereader:
        name = row[0]
        # Deal with the A folder
        try:
            os.rename('A/' + name, 'New folder/' + name)
            print(name + " moved to new folder.")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass # Not found in A
        # Deal with the B folder
        try:
            os.rename('B/' + name, 'New folder/' + name)
            print(name + " moved to new folder.")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass # Not found in B
        except FileExistsError:
            pass # Name clash
```

If you want to customize your .csv file, modify how the `name = row[0]` line as the `row` is an array of values in a given .csv row. You can also handle cases where both `A/1111.png` and `B/1111.png` occurs.

Please note this code uses relative paths, so if you want the `blabla/blabla2/blabla3/...` to work you may need to create the folders `blabla/blabla2/blabla3/` from the folder containing the python file.