# How to copy files from cloud storage to other cloud? For example, Google Drive to OneDrive

Tags: python

I want to copy the files from Google Drive to OneDrive using any APIs in Python. Google provides some APIs but I don't see anything related to copy the files to another cloud.

One way to achieve this is like download files from Google Drive using Google Drive API and again upload to OneDrive.

Please share some inputs if there is a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running both services on your desktop, you could just use python to move the files from one folder to another. See [How to move a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python). By moving the file from your google drive folder to your onedrive folder, the services should automatically sync and upload the files.

(As an aside, another solution if you don't care how the problem gets solved a service like https://publist.app might be of use).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do not have the services installed. I want to do it programmatically.