# Archiving Files Using Python Apart from Latest File

Tags: python, python-3.x, archive, fme

I am trying to archive existing file apart from the latest modified file in Python or FME. I have managed to get it to point where I can get python pick up the latest modified file but any ideas on how I can archive all the files i have in my folder apart from the last modified file?

Thank You

Comment: could you show an example directory, what it looks like before and the expected outcome?

Comment: A simple directory, do you mean like file path? D:\Documents\test = where the files appear on daily basis. You will for example have 10 files in there. I would like to move them to D:\Documents\archive 9 of the files out of 10. Keep the latest date modified file.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python

Comment: Thanks. Just had a look, there is possibly some of it which helps but unsure if there is anyway where it can pick up the latest file only and archives the rest of the files.

Comment: You can use [os.path.getmtime](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime) to find the times and pick the most recent and move all the others? I can make an answer if this sounds like it would work.

Comment: That may work. I can adjust it if it does play up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem using this snippet of code:

```
import glob
import os
import zipfile

files_dir = r'C:\Users\..\files' # here should be path to directory with your files
files = glob.glob(files_dir + '\*')
# find all files that located in specified directory
files_modify_dt = [os.path.getmtime(file) for file in files]
# take files except last modified file
files_to_zip = [file for _, file in sorted(zip(files_modify_dt, files))][:-1]
# zip of selected files
with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(files_dir, 'archive.zip'), 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip_obj:
    for file in files_to_zip:
        zip_obj.write(file, os.path.basename(file))
        os.remove(file)
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i was after. Thanks for your help