# Copy contents of a binary file from local to remote server

Tags: binary, copy, scp

Often as a shorthand, to copy credentials from one machine to another, I will copy-paste the contents into a file on the remote server. Is there a way to do this with binary data? For example, I have a python `.pickle` file that I would like to copy to another location. Aside from using another utility such as `scp` or `git`, is it possible to copy/paste the data to the remote file?

Note: this is not about hot to copy a file locally. I am asking how do I copy-paste the contents of a binary file on my local machine to a remote machine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python). Alternatively, [How do I copy a file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python?rq=1)

Comment: @MarkSnyder no -- one file is opened locally and one is on a remote server.

Comment: What OS are your local and remote machines running?

Comment: @MarkSnyder locally it's a mac and remote is ubuntu.

Comment: Do you already have the capability to mount your remote server locally? Because as Isterzinger's answer suggests, if you do then you should be able to do it using the linked methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using software that can mount the remote server's directory locally, your operating system's file copy-paste system should be able to transfer the file over.

Otherwise, as you stated, a utility like scp, sftp, rsync, or similar would work very well for this.