# Rewrite files from one folder an other and rename them

Tags: python, file

A short question. I have multiple files in a tester folder on my desktop. Now I want to rewrite all those files, add 'moved' at the end of their filename and move them to a new folder named tester1 also on my desktop. Someone any idea? Thank you in advance. This is my current code:

```
source = r'c:\data\AS\Desktop\tester'

#Take the absolute filepaths from all the files in tester and open them.
for file in os.listdir(source):
    file_paths = os.path.join(source, file)
    with open(file_paths, 'r') as rf:
        print(rf.read() + '\n')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file)

Comment: Its not as specific as mine :(

Comment: Instead of reading the file and then writing the contents to a new file just do normal file copy/rename operation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python

Comment: You want to **rewrite** files or just **move** them to a new location with a modified name?

Comment: I want to move them to a new location with a modified name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will work if you have extensions in your file and you want 'moved' to be added before extension:

```py
    import os
    import shutil

    src_path = "c:/data/AS/Desktop/tester/"
    dest_path = "c:/data/AS/Desktop/tester1/"

    for file in os.listdir(src_path):
        file_name, extension = file.split(".")
        shutil.move(src_path + file, dest_path + file_name + "moved." + extension)
```

If you don't have extensions in your files, then the code can be changed as below:

```py
    import os
    import shutil

    src_path = "c:/data/AS/Desktop/tester/"
    dest_path = "c:/data/AS/Desktop/tester1/"

    for file_name in os.listdir(src_path):
        shutil.move(src_path + file_name, dest_path + file_name + "moved")
```

I have checked this in MacOS, let me know in the comments if you face any issue in Windows.

Comment: I used your second block of code, it seems very logical but I get the following error: 
    [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Comment: can you check now, I just fixed the issue with path.

Comment: Now that worked, thank you very much! But what did you actually change or do to make it work?

Comment: I replaced the backward slash to forward slash and also added one more slash in end of the path.

Comment: Why did you chose to change those slashles? Wasnt it possible to make use of the 'r' before the pathname?

Comment: Yes, you can use `r''` as it converts it to raw string, but I actually tested it on Mac, and in Mac the paths are of forward slash so raw string won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can use:-

```
import os
SourceFile="C:/Myfolder/Source/MyFile.txt"
TargetFile="C:/MyFolder/Target/MyFile_moved.txt"
os.rename(SourceFile,TargetFile)
```

Hope helps.

Comment: I get t the following error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:

Comment: I have updated the code to give you the full example so that you can try it. The error you got might be because of the path or non-existence of the file (most probably the path). You could be using "\" instead of "/". Please check that once as well.

Comment: Thank you anyway, but I have used the answer above which makes it possible for multiple files.

Comment: No issues. Happy to hear that you found a solution that worked for you.