# Rename(change) file name and remove data (specific characters) using Python

Tags: python

I coded how to load and save txt file using pandas in python.

```py
import glob

filenames = sorted(glob.glob("D:/a/test*.txt"))
filenames = filenames[0:5]

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

for f in filenames:
  df = pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=[1,2,3], dtype=str, delim_whitespace=True) 
  df.to_csv(f'{f[:-4]}.csv', index=False)

 ------>There are 10 result files in a folder 
 - test1.txt, test2.txt, test3.txt, test4.txt, test5.txt, 
 test1.csv, test2.csv, test3.csv, test4.csv, test5.csv

#Result csv.file(test1.csv)

abc:,1.233e-03
1.234e-04,
1.235e-02,
1.236e-05,
1.237e-02,
1.238e-02,
```

But I have some problems as follows.

1. I don't know how to rename test1.txt, test2.txt, test3.txt, test4.txt, test5.txt into c1.csv, c2.csv, c3.csv, c4.csv, c5.csv.
2. I want remove 'abc:,'data in all test(1,2,3,4,5).csv files, but I don't know how to delete and replace data.

Do you know how to rename(change) file name and remove data (specific character) referred to above problems in python?

```
origin data
test1.txt (it is similar to other file-{test2,test3,test4, test5}.txt)
abc:  1.233e-03
def:  1.64305155216978164e+02
ghi: 4831
jkl:
 1.234e-04
 1.235e-02
 1.236e-05
 1.237e-02
 1.238e-02

Expected result
(it must chage test1,2,3,4,5.txt files into c1,2,3,4,5.csv files, it only remove herder name(abc:), also def:,ghi:,jkl: rows should remove.)
 1.233e-03
 1.234e-04
 1.235e-02
 1.236e-05
 1.237e-02
 1.238e-02
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd


for f in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    df = pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=[1,2,3], dtype=str, delim_whitespace=True)
    df = df.replace('abc:,','')
    os.rename(f,f'{f[:-4]}.csv')
    df.to_csv(f'{f[:-4]}.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215669/discussion-on-answer-by-ann-zen-renamechange-file-name-and-remove-data-specif).

Answer (score 0):

1. You can rename your file using [os.rename()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-rename-method) method or you can create a new file using `f= open("file_name.extension","w+")` and write the output to new file.
2. You can use the `replace()` method once you load your data into a string variable.

Comment: -I want to use code like 'df.read_csv' and 'to_csv'. Do you know how to solve different type?
I already replace()-replace('abc:,', ''). but it also occurrs the error.