# How to move Files from one folder to another folder from python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df1:

```
   Country   Product
0  Columbia  Shoes
1  Brazil    Football

folder1_files: 

col_sho.csv
Bra_foo.csv
Gha_cof.csv

fold1_path='c:/folder1'
fold2_path='c:/foder2'
```

I need to move some files from folder 1 to folder2 based on the information from df1. You can see in df1 there are two countries and Product.Based on that information col_shoe.csv and bra_foo.csv files needs to copied in the folder2.

Comment: To get the filename from the DataFrame object you can try: `files = df.apply(lambda x: ('_'.join((x.str[:3]).str.lower())+'.csv'),axis=1).tolist()` will give you list of filenames like`['bra_foo.csv', 'col_sho.csv']` Then you can use `os.rename('folder1/'+files[0],'folder2/'+files[0])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using clear names for files will help in moving file easy.

```
import shutil
import os
import pandas as pd
folder1 = "./folder1"
folder2 = "./folder2"


df = pd.DataFrame({"Country":["Columbia", "Brazil"], "Product":["Shoes","Football"]})
s = df["Country"].str[:3] + "_" + df["Product"].str[:3] + ".csv"
for file_name in s.values:
    if os.path.isfile(folder1 + os.path.sep + file_name):
        shutil.move(folder1 + os.path.sep + file_name, folder2 + os.path.sep + file_name)
    else:
        print("file {} is not available".format(file_name))
```

If you want to use lower case letters only, then you can use

```
df["Country"].str[:3].str.lower()
```