# How do I move a text file to a different folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I already know how to create and write a text file in Python, but how do I move that file to a different folder on my system?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8858026/10306224

Answer (score 0):

You can either make a system call with `os.system`:

```py
import os
os.system("mv /path/to/file /path/to/destination")
```

or rename it:

````py
os.rename("/path/to/file", "/path/to/destination")
or move it with `shutil.move`:  
```python
import shutil

shutil.move("/path/to/file", "/path/to/destination")
````

First solution works only in bash shells, second and third should be portable over all platforms. Third has the advantage that you can specify a folder as destination, the file will then be put into that folder with the same name as in the old location.