# how do i move the new screenshots into the dir folder

Tags: python

Basically I can't figure out how to make the new screenshots go into the folder. if there's a way for the folder to be created and even then run the code of taking screenshots within the new folder, it would help a lot.

[Here's a screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVTS7.png)

Comment: You can use this reference to move the file to another directory.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file)

Comment: Does it work if you change the .s you have between the timestamp to something like a -

Comment: Hi Tristan! Please, do not post screenshots of your code, it will make it harder for you to have responses. You could take a read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make sure you maximize the chances of getting good answers!