# Moving All Contents Within Files to New Folder?

Tags: python, automation, move, glob

I have several folders that have a naming convention of "monthly_vendor_report_####", where #### is just a random combination of numbers. Each folder has a CSV file and I'd like to move the CSVs files out of the folder to a new destination source. So far this is what I have, which only unzips the files:

```
import os, zipfile

dir_name = r"C:\Users\...."
extension = ".zip"

os.chdir(dir_name) # change directory from working dir to dir with files

for item in os.listdir(dir_name): # loop through items in dir
    if item.endswith(extension): # check for ".zip" extension
        file_name = os.path.abspath(item) # get full path of files
        zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(file_name) # create zipfile object
        zip_ref.extractall(dir_name) # extract file to dir
        zip_ref.close() # close file
        os.remove(file_name) # delete zipped file
```

[Screenshot of folders--each folder contains a CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDvMn.png)

[Content of one of the folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yO8I.png)

Comment: Which is it: CSV or ZIP files? The code indicates ZIP but the text indicates CSV.

Comment: CSV--I receive the files as a ZIP, so the code above only unzips the folders.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file)

Comment: Not completely. I'm not sure how to create a loop where it moves the content of each folder--also considering the wildcard folder names.

Comment: Try combining that answer with the documentation for [flow control](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements). Dump the code for moving a single file into a `for` loop.

Comment: Are the CSV files take the same names as their folders?

Comment: @AziMez Yes, they do.

Comment: What does unzipping zip files have to do with your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  shutil to `copy` or `move` the files.

#Note that *all* the CSV files are taking the *same* names as their folders

```
import os
import shutil

# Open a file
path = 'C:\foo'
os.chdir(path)

dirs = filter(os.path.isdir, os.listdir(path))

destination= 'C:\Output'

# This would copy all listed CSV files 
for dir in dirs:
   file= dir + ".csv" 
   src= path + "\\" + dir + "\\" + file 
   shutil.copy(src, destination)
```