# Move downloaded torrent after finished downloading libtorrent

Tags: python, libtorrent

I am downloading torrents using libtorrent. The torrents have different download locations (save_path). I wish to move a downloaded torrent to new location after it finishes downloading.
New location depends on pre-existing save_path.

```
ses = lt.session()
downloads=[]
.
.
params = {"save_path": "some/path"}
downloads.append(lt.add_magnet_uri(ses,  magnet_link, params))
.
.
.

    for index, download in enumerate(downloads[:]):
        if not download.is_seed():
            s = download.status()

            /....DO SOMETHING..../

        else:
            ses.remove_torrent(download)
            downloads.remove(download)
            
            #path of downloaded file
            #download.status().save_path 

            /...MOVE FILES TO NEW LOCATION.../

            print(download.name(), "complete")
```

1. How do I get save_path of downloaded torrent ***DONE***
2. How do I move downloaded files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi according to follwoing commit on github [libtorrent](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/pull/503/commits/472144be7758e4fbf95ad039ed444de09103d023) or rather the [test.py](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/blob/RC_2_0/bindings/python/test.py). I would guess that you get the `save_path` like this:

```
s = download.status()
s.save_path
```

I could not test it. Hope it works.

Move a file, is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file)

```
import shutil
shutil.move(s.save_path, "path/to/new/destination/")
```

Comment: I wanted to use libtorrent's methods for moving but this does the trick. Thanks :)