# how would you move files from one destination to another sorted by file type?

Tags: python, file

so i am trying to make a program in python where you can move files from one directory to another, and i am trying to figure out how i could sort the moving of files by their extension or file type. how would you do this?

Comment: Can you please specify the actual task? Did you try anything? Are you familiar with the Python standard libraries?

Answer (score -1):

Apart from using `os.lisdir()` to find the names and sort,
[this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python) will teach you how to move files in Python3