# How to use askopenfile()?

Tags: python, tkinter, filedialog

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to use askopenfiles() from tkinter.filedialog to move a file to another folder? If so can I have an example

Comment: What code do you already have?  `askopenfile` puts up a dialog that asks the user to choose a file.  That's all it does.  It doesn't do any moving.  You have to do that yourself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python does this answer your question?

Comment: I know tried getting the file with askopenfile() and moving it with os but nothing works @Keon

Comment: Please show what you've tried. Your question is unclear since there are countless examples on the internet for how to use `askopenfile`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation, and is not a discussion forum. The way to answer your question is to put something like `tkinter askopenfile` into a search engine; and if you don't understand what is written there, you should try asking somewhere like Reddit or Quora unless you have a *specific* question with a code example.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I was using the wrong function, askopenfile() does not working with moving funtions in os such as os.rename or shutil.move, I had to use askopenfilename() instead so it looks like this.

```
def getv():
    shutil.move(str(askopenfilename()), 'C:\\Users\\ezedd\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Python Projects\\Converter')
```