# How to download the files to a folder inside a project directory? (Selenium)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

The project directory looks like:

```
project
 -temp
 -program.py
```

This code downloads the file but does not download the file in the desired folder. I want the downloaded file  in temp folder.

program.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
# 0 for desktop
# 1 for default download folder
# 2 for specific folder
# You can specify directory by using profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir","<>")
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir","temp/")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False);
```

Comment: what is the `location` of downloaded file?

Comment: the file downloads on the default download folder of firefox.

Comment: try full path of the folder temp here: `profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir","temp/")` and tell me the result; example: `/home/$user/.../.../project/temp`

Answer (score 0):

okay this is not the exact solution, but it's a workaround.

what if we just move the file from where it got downloaded to temp folder ?

```
from pathlib import Path

Path("path/to/current/file.foo").rename("path/to/new/destination/for/file.foo")
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python) to learn more how we can move a file in Python.