# Need to move multiple files to a new directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, directory, move

So I am brand new to python and very stumped. I have a list of files and need to read the files, and find the year '2012' then move those files into a new directory labeled 2012. I have managed to get the list of my files. but have not been able to figure out a way to get them all into a new directory. thank you in advance

````
    if filename.startswith("ff_"):
        file=open(os.path.join(base, filename),'r')
        for x in file:
            if '2012' in x:   
               print(filename)```
````

Comment: You can use `os.makedirs()` to create the 2012 directory and then use `shutil.move()` to move the files to the new location. I like `pathlib`, so personally I'd probably represent paths as `Path` instances and use `Path.mkdir()` instead of `os`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I hope below code is the solution for your problem. Please note that I have use `os.mkdirs()` to create new directory. but you can try with `Path.mkdir()`

I have created four text file. out of 4, three text file have strings 2012. and one text file contains string 2020 and three text file contains 2012

Input files:

1. ff1.txt (contains string `"2012"`)
2. ff2.txt (doesn't contains string `"2012"`)
3. ff_blah1.txt (contains string `"2012"`)
4. ff_blah1_blah2.txt (contains string `"2012"`)

I have broken down problem statement in steps

1. find the files which has name starts with `"ff"`
2. after finding files, open all the files and search string `"2012"`
3. create new folder `"2012"` if it doesn't exists
4. move all files that we find at step2 into new created folder `"2012"`

> ```
> import os
> import shutil
>
> source_path = '/Users/MacJJ271123/Desktop/PY_Script/'
> list_of_files = os.listdir(source_path)
>
> def move_file():
>     for file in list_of_files:
>         if file.startswith("ff"):
>             if '2012' in open(file).read():
>                 if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(source_path, "2012")):
>                     os.mkdir(os.path.join(source_path, "2012"))
>                 shutil.move(os.path.join(source_path,file), os.path.join(source_path,"2012",file))
>                 print(file)
>
> move_file()
> ```

Output:

```
MacJ271123-MacBook-Air~  # python3 move_files_stack_oveflow.py
ff_blah1_blah2.txt
ff_blah1.txt
ff1.txt
MacJJ271123-MacBook-Air~  #
```