# Moving only images in a directory to a new directory

Tags: python, file, directory, shutil

I have a directory containing N images, but each image is itself contained in a subdirectory, which is otherwise empty. It looks like this:

```
- Images
 - Image1
   - image1.jpg
 - Image2
   - image2.jpg
 - Image3
   - image3.jpg
 - Image4
...etc
```

I would like to move it to a new directory that will contain only the images, like so:

```
- New Directory
 - image1.jpg
 - image2.jpg
 - image3.jpg
...etc
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This will involve writing code, which you do not appear to have even attempted to do.

Comment: Why bother writing a program?  `mv */*.jpg NewDirectory/.`

Comment: I imagine that this is a one off migration. I would recommend that you do it directly in the terminal, if you have access whether directly or via SSH.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thank you, however as far as I can tell, this doesn't move all the images at once. Is there a bash command that allows you to move all images at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple solution ended up working for me:

```
import os

rootdir = './Images'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
  for file in files:
    os.rename((os.path.join(subdir, file)),'./NewDirectory/'+str(file))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import os, shutil, pathlib, fnmatch
    
    def move_dir(src: str, dst: str, pattern: str = '*'):
        if not os.path.isdir(dst):
            pathlib.Path(dst).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        for f in fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(src), pattern):
            shutil.move(os.path.join(src, f), os.path.join(dst, f))
#easy to use
    move_dir('Images/Image1','New Directory','jpg')
```

Source: [How to move a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python)