# Copy latest version of a file (with Diferent filenames) every month

Tags: python, windows, powershell, robocopy

I need to copy the newest version of a file from A directory to B directory.

The files are generated monthly and are called `"20220101 File.txt" "20220201 File.txt" "20220301 File.txt"` and so on.

How can I copy every month the "latest" version of the file? For example, on August, the file `"20220801 File.txt"` should be copied to B directory.

I have copied it "manually" using Robocopy, but I don't know how to do it automatically.

It doesn't matter if Python is used or any other tool.

Comment: You might want to share some code, either python or powershell to have better chances at someone helping you instead of expecting to have it coded for you

Answer (score 1):

assuming it is not a directory containing a huge number of files this should do what you want:

```
$destinationPath = "C:\folderA"
$sourcePath =  "C:\folderB"
$newestFile = (get-childitem $sourcePath | Sort-Object -Property CreationTime -Descending)[0]

copy-item -Path $newestFile.pspath -Destination $destinationPath -force
```

It does not recognize the date information in the filename, it uses the creationDate of the file to identify the newest one.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can easily do it with **Python**.

```
from datetime import datetime
import shutil
    
month = str(datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m'))+ "01 File.txt" #it will be 20220901 File.txt
src_path = f"C:\A\{month}"
dst_path = f"C:\B\{month}"
shutil.copyfile(src_path, dst_path) #I copy the file from directory A and paste it on directory B , the destination file will have the same name of the original file.
```

Comment: Nice solution, avoids using extra indexing and uses domain format.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just joined StackOverFlow and I feel extremely happy that a random user just  congratulated me

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with @Santiago, didn't provide any attempt to solve the problem.

That being said, with a few libraries this is possible to do easily. Mainly combination of finding all the files in A directory (using `glob`), and copying the file in the new directory (using `shutil`).

```
import shutil
from glob import glob
from datetime import date

location_1 = "in"
location_2 = "out"

files_to_copy = glob(f"{location_1}/*.txt")
files_to_copy.sort() # think glob already gives in sorted order, but added just in case

file_to_copy = files_to_copy[-1]
name = file_to_copy.split("/")[-1]
shutil.copy(file_to_copy, f"{location_2}/{name}")
```

if  you want to add information about date or you replace the last line with:

```
shutil.copy(file_to_copy, f"{location_2}/{date.today().strftime('%d_%m_%Y')}_{name}")
```

For reference look up [stackoverflow about moving files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python) and [how to get current time in python](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/current-datetime) besides the documentation from the libraries already mentioned.