# How do I copy all folder contents from one location to another location in Python?

Tags: python, windows, copy, coding-style, paste

I have been trying to make a python file that will copy contents from one folder to another. I would like it to work on any Windows system that I run it on. It must copy ALL things ...

i need solution to this problem.

Comment: Hi, please check here I think this will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python

Answer (score 0):

```
import shutil
import os

# Path to the directory
source = 'C:/path/to/source/folder'

# Path to the destination directory
destination = 'C:/path/to/destination/folder'

# Copy contents from source to destination
shutil.copytree(source, destination)

# List all the files in source directory
source_files = os.listdir(source)

# Iterate over all the files in source directory
for file_name in source_files:
    # Create full path of file in source directory
    full_file_name = os.path.join(source, file_name)
    # If file is a directory, create corresponding directory in destination
    # directory
    if os.path.isdir(full_file_name):
        shutil.copytree(full_file_name, os.path.join(destination, file_name))
    else:
        # Copy the file from source to destination
        shutil.copy2(full_file_name, destination)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import shutil
import os

source = 'C:/path/to/source/folder'

destination = 'C:/path/to/destination/folder'

shutil.copytree(source, destination)

source_files = os.listdir(source)

for file_name in source_files:
    
    full_file_name = os.path.join(source, file_name)
    
    if os.path.isdir(full_file_name):
        shutil.copytree(full_file_name, os.path.join(destination, file_name))
    else:
        shutil.copy2(full_file_name, destination)
```