# Python - move files from one folder to another

Tags: python

looking for an extension to my code below, so when the condition **is not met** files will be moved to "ERROR" folder. Anyone who can help? Thank you :-)

```py
source = '/Users/XY/Desktop/OUT'
destination = '/Users/XY/Desktop/IN'

allfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(source, '*S*'), recursive=True)
print("Files to move", allfiles)

for file_path in allfiles:
    dst_path = os.path.join(destination, os.path.basename(file_path))
    shutil.move(file_path, dst_path)
    print(f"Moved {file_path} -> {dst_path}")
```

I tried to search on google but without luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python

Comment: Another option: after you've moved all the matching files, the files remaining are those that did not match.

Answer (score -1):

```
for file_path in allfiles:
    if some_condition:
        dst_path = os.path.join(destination, os.path.basename(file_path))
    else:
        dst_path = os.path.join(error_folder, os.path.basename(file_path))
    shutil.move(file_path, dst_path)
    print(f"Moved {file_path} -> {dst_path}")
```