# I am trying to import a file using import os but it's keeps saying directory not empty

Tags: python

```
Import os
source="/storage/emulated/0/converted.py"
destination="/storage/emulated/0/DCIM"
try:
    if os.path.exists(destination):
        print("file already there")
    if os.replace(source,destination):
        print(source+ " was moved")
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(source+ " file was not found")
```

After trying import a file to another I get an error "directory not empty"
I am new to coding so I am bit confused,should the destination be empty before importing? and lastly I sometimes get an error saying "not a directory" and I was just wondering if I can only transfer files from directory to directory alone? or can transfer from both(directory and folder)?
Thanks in advance for your answer❤️

Comment: If the destination exists, did you want to stop processing after your print()?

Comment: [Friendly docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74901615/i-am-trying-to-import-a-file-using-import-os-but-its-keeps-saying-directory-not): ". If dst is a directory, OSError will be raised." Also: "The operation may fail if src and dst are on different filesystems.". You probably want `shutil.move` instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python#8858026

Comment: Yea both are in the same filesystem but I would try your suggestion also(shutil.move) I appreciate 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `os.replace()` function will replace the file or directory at the **destination** path with the file or directory at the **source** path. **If the destination path already exists and is not empty**, you will get a "*directory not empty*" error because the function cannot replace a non-empty directory. So to fix that you can check `if not os.listdir(destination)` then apply the `os.replace()`,

Your full code will be something like this-

```
import os
source = "/storage/emulated/0/converted.py"
destination = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM"

# Check if the destination path exists
if os.path.exists(destination):
    # If the destination path exists, check if it is empty
    if not os.listdir(destination):
        # If the destination path is empty, call os.replace()
        if os.replace(source, destination):
            print(source + " was moved to " + destination)
    else:
        # If the destination path is not empty
        print("The destination path is not empty")
else:
    # If the destination path does not exist
    print("The destination path does not exist")
```

Comment: So basically the destination should be empty?

Answer (score 0):

destination should be the full path of the file i.e.:

```
destination = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/converted.py"
```

Otherwise you're trying to replace a folder "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/" with a file "/storage/emulated/0/converted.py"