# Move file using specific nav path to another folder

Tags: python, pandas, file, directory, shutil

I have a list of navigation paths to specific files, which all come from different folders. I'd like to move them all to a new folder.

Specifically, my data is formatted in two columns in a dataframe, where I'd like to move each file to its new folder. (Each row describes a file.)

My input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'old_path': ['/Users/myname/images/cat/file_0.jpg', '/Users/myname/images/dog/file_1.jpg', '/Users/myname/images/squirrel/file_2.jpg'], 
                  'new_path': ['/Users/myname/mydir/file_0.jpg', '/Users/myname/mydir/file_1.jpg', '/Users/myname/mydir/file_2.jpg'], 
                 })
```

However, I have yet to figure out how to modify the code below to do this in a loop or anything similarly helpful: [How to move a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python)

```
import os
import shutil

shutil.move("path/to/current/file.foo", "path/to/new/destination/for/file.foo")
```

In this example, all the files are being moved to the same folder. But, it'd be great if the answered code were generalizable to send files to different folders, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) with a `for` loop:

```
for old, new in zip(df['old_path'], df['new_path']):
    shutil.move(old, new)
```