# create and move to a new directory

Tags: python, directory, working-directory

I'm writing a program that asks the user to input the name of a new folder.  then it creates the path and moves to it to save some data.

I have the code to ask and create the path, but can't get it quite right to move to the new relative location.

```
new_dir = input('Enter the directory where you want to save your data :').lower()
if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
    os.makedirs(new_dir)
```

it creates the path, but I'm still saving dataset to the cwd

Comment: where is your code to move to that directory and save the data there? [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Show the code that saves the data (properly formatted in the question).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For future questions, please try to focus on **the question**.  Saying things like "but can't get it quite right to move to the new relative location" isn't very helpful - this implies *that the code you're showing includes an attempt to do that*. If you mean that you think the existing code should do that, then you should explicitly ask that: "why doesn't this code have that effect?" If you mean that you just don't know how to do it, ask that instead.

Comment: But before asking, [please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to look for existing Q&A - for example by [using a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+change+to+a+new+directory).

Answer (score -2):

I just browsed some answers and found that there is a library named 'shutil' which has function 'move()'. You can try

```
import shutil
shutil.move("path/to/current/file.foo", "path/to/new/destination/for/file.foo")
```

for more detailed answer please refer [How do I move a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-do-i-move-a-file-in-python). Hope this meets your needs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The goal is not to move a file, but to change the current working directory ("move to" that folder, so that future operations will take place there). But aside from that, if you think a question already has a "more detailed answer" somewhere else on Stack Overflow, **please do not answer it** - instead, flag the question as a duplicate, to help close it properly. We do not want answers for duplicate questions on Stack Overflow - we want the relevant information all in the same place. We do not want custom answers that address the OP - we want a searchable library.

Comment: Please read [answer] to understand the policy properly.

Comment: Okay. I will try to improve the answer, if possible or will delete it. Thanks for helping.