# Moving Files to a different directory using OS python module

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system

I was doing a project about directory and file manipulation with os module, in the os module. Do I have to specify th file`s path in os.rename() function in order to move him to a different directory?Do I have to specify which file path I want to?

I didn`t try a lot of things, I have some doubts about how we can use os.rename() method to move a file or directory to another place in storage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I move a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-do-i-move-a-file-in-python)